# Codeigniter3 can't remove index.php on xampp

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I know there's so many topic about this, but I've tried and that isn't work.

my ci is located at `htdocs/codeigniter3`

I saw .htaccess inside of `codeigniter3/application` folder, but I leave it alone. I create new .htaccess on root folder `codeigniter3` (outside of `application`)

my .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

also on config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter3/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

on httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

this mod_rewrite.so file also avaiable on `apache/modules`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your .htaccess file

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /YOUR_PROJECT_NAME
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: well, it's totally works!

So, if I rename my project, I should modify it again.

hmm... wonder if there's any settings for that

Answer (score 0):

Edit your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

it work both local and live form me